# How can I get CLion to append a comment after the closing namespace brace?

Tags: ide, code-generation, ui-automation, clion, code-completion

In CLion (e.g. 2021.2), if you type `namespace foo`, nothing special happens. I would have liked it if this would get me:

```
namespace foo {



} // namespace foo
```

with the cursor on the middle line. How close can I get to making that happen?

Comment: How unfair. I have the opposite problem actually. How do I get rid of the CLion behaviour that you want? If I remove the`// namespace foo` then it will reappear automatically after formatting, but there is nothing in my .clang-format file or my .clang-tidy file that specifies such behaviour 8-(

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: This must mean there is some code generation rule defined.  Anyway, just ask a question here on SO if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: Gotit, its the default behaviour of `clang-format`. Adding `FixNamespaceComments: false` fixes the issue for me. It does not remove comments, it just does not add them an more. You should be fine with setting it to `true`. Its better than the Live Template solution because .clang-format should be in the repo so everyone does the same. BTW, the Live Template solution below does not work with my CLion EAP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967152) answer, and with full credit to you for getting this far, I have progressed this such that the Live Template behaviour you seek is automatically invoked just by typing `namespace<space>`.

To set this up, create the Live Template as per that answer, but make sure:

1. The name of the Live Template *must* be `namespace`, as this is used to select this template once expansion is triggered, and
2. Set the template text to include the `$END$` variable, as that sets the final cursor position to be within the new namespace:

```
namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME$ {
$END$
} // namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME$
```

3. Set the drop-down "Expand with Default (Tab)" to "Expand with Space". This will cause the space character you type after the `namespace` keyword to automatically trigger the selection of the template.

[image: Settings Dialog > Editor > Live Templates]

Now you can type `namespace<space>my_namespace` and it will automatically create the following text, as you type, with no need to select from a dropdown or hit Tab, and the cursor will be placed at the start of the blank line within the new namespace:

```
namespace my_namespace {

} // namespace my_namespace
```

Comment: How does the `$END` variable help?

Comment: That indicates where the cursor ends up after "accepting" the substitution - you asked for "with the cursor on the middle line." - that's what that does :)

Comment: Thanks to @davidA and @einpoklum for the excellent work-around solutions. The only caveats are (1) the namespace names in the comments don't get updated with refactoring and (2) definition of a namespace alias, e.g. `namespace x = y.z;` can also trigger the live template. There is a CLion issue folks can thumb-up and track for the complete solution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14711/Add-automatic-labels-to-closing-braces-for-classes-namespaces-and-functions.

Comment: Yes, item (2) is a bit of a pain. It can be worked around by changing the Live Template name from `namespace` to something like `xnamespace`, and then remembering to type that instead. Not ideal, but workable if it becomes a big problem for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

The best I could manage:

1. On the menus, go to: **File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates**.
2. In the tree view of templates, select **C/C++**.
3. Press the tiny `+` button on the side-bar (far edge of the dialog; why do JetBrains like tiny controls so much?).
4. Create a template:

   - Name: "namespace"
   - Description: whatever you like
   - Template text:

     ```
     namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME$ {

     } // namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME$
     ```
   - No need to edit the variables.
   - reformat according to style enabled (I guess?)
   - Applicable in: C++ Declaration.

Now, when you type `namespace`, the completion box will have an option with your chosen description. If you choose it (you still need to press Down-Key once or twice to get to it), then press Enter, you'll get the braces, and a cursor with which you'll need to type the namespace name only once.

This is far from perfect, but it's something.